# How to replace variables in equation in python

Tags: python, equation, replace

I have string with some equation, that include variables. For example:

```
eq='(a+1)*c-d'
```

Also I have dictionary with values for variables. For example:

```
val={'a':5,'c':'k','d':'300n'}
```

As You can see in same cases value of variable can be other variable, and in some cases not all variables from eq will be in val.

I need to replace all variables in eq with values from val.
Of cause straight forward code will be something like:

```
for v in val.keys():
  eq=re.sub(v,val[v],eq)
```

But this code will fail in some cases. For example when in variables list will be variables "n" and "nn"

So, can someone think about better solution?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have another dictionary for those variables (which are in values part of dictionary you have shown)?? How would you replace their value??

Comment: No, I have no other dictionary. In my case it will be ok to leave some variables in equation. The equation not always need to be calculated to single number.

Comment: @Alex.. Man. Then what's bothering you??

Comment: so your expected output in this case is `kkkkkk-300n`?

Comment: @Rohit Jain All variables with known values must be replaced with their values. I have hierarchical structure and variables need to be propagated from top level to bottom level. So in each level variables need to be replaced with variables from previous level.

Comment: How about `re.sub('\\b'+v+'\\b', ...` ?

Comment: @Alex.. And you haven't talked about this `hierarchy` anywhere in your original post...

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary in my example i expect to get (5+1)*k-300n

Comment: @Rohit Jain is it really meter? I have much larger problem, but other parts already solved. This is showstopper now.

Comment: @Vaughn Cato It seems ok. I will try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for k,v in val.items():
    eq = re.sub(r'\b' + k + r'\b', v, eq)
```

This will search for variables by their full name, i.e. if the `val = {'x': '5'}` and the equation contains substrings like "xx", "x2", or even "2x", these strings will not be replaced.

Comment: It seem ok on small example. Will see if it works good on actual data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach requires changing the formula around just a smidge and uses the string function 'format'.

Using keyword arguments (not very programmatic):

```
>>> '({a}+1)*{c}-{d}'.format(a=5, c='k', d='300n')
'(5+1)*k-300n'
```

Or alternatively using a dict:

```
>>> '({a}+1)*{c}-{d}'.format(**{'a': 5, 'c': 'k', 'd': '300n'})
'(5+1)*k-300n'
```

Doing so may help users identify when something isn't replaced, or is meant to be replaced, and simplifies the code quite a bit.

Comment: The problem is that equation is string with unknown number of variables. So solution must be generic for any eq and val

Comment: `>>> '({a}{a}{a}+1)*{c}-{d}'.format(**{'a': 5, 'c': 'k', 'd': '300n'})
'(555+1)*k-300n'`

Comment: @whardier how will you evaluate it?